# Integral lifts of families of varieties over a finite field

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

Let $X\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:F_q[[t]]$ be a flat morphism with smooth proper geometrically connected fibers. Suppose the central fiber lifts to a scheme $X'_0$ smooth proper over $W(F_q)$. Is our family the base change of a flat morphism with smooth proper fibers $X'\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:W(F_q)[[t]]$ whose central fiber is $X'_0$? is our family the base change of *any* flat morphism with smooth proper fibers $X'\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:W(F_q)[[t]]$?

If the answer is "no", what additional conditions are required? Is it enough to demand that the central and the generic fiber lift to smooth proper schemes in possibly unrelated ways?

Comment: A negative answer to the first two questions follows from Murphy's Law, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411469, I think, because we can just choose the deformation space to be $\mathbb W(F_q)[t]/ (pt)$. For the generic fiber, it might depend on what field you demand it lift over.